# How to make ExecuteAsync run async

Tags: c#, .net, background-service

I have asp.net app with worker service initialized like this.

```
builder.Services.AddHostedService<XXX>();
```

And then service worker itself.

```
public class XXX : BackgroundService
{
    readonly ILogger<XXX> _logger;

    public XXX(ILogger<XXX> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Service Started.");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Service Stopped.");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    protected async override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
       new MyInfiniteLoopClass();
    }
}
```

In method ExecuteAsync I am creating class MyInfiniteLoopClass which consist of infinity loop lets say `while(true)`.

Problem is that swagger runs only when I break that infinity cycle. Which means that entire asp.net app stops on that method. How can I make side by side?

Comment: Please note that the BackgroundWorker tag has nothing to do with your question (which is an old class coming with .NET *Framework* 2.0), so I replaced the BackgroundWorker tag with BackgroundService.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue in ASP.NET Core.
You can add `await Task.Yield()` to the top of the `ExecuteAsync()` and it will work:

```cs
protected async override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
   await Task.Yield();

   new MyInfiniteLoopClass();
}
```

More info: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36063